# Energy given to a Coin during a Coin Toss

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotation

Suppose I toss a coin by flicking it with my thumb at a point distant $x$ away from its center. Say my finger imparts it a linear impulse $J$ at that point.

Correct me if I’m wrong, but then the angular velocity $\omega$ and translational velocity $v$ it acquires are given by $$\omega = \frac{Jx}{I} \\ v = \frac{J}{m} $$

For one, the independence of $v$ and $x$ seems a bit odd, because my intuition tells me that hitting the coin at its center should give it a higher velocity as compared to hitting it at its edge.

The energy given to the coin is then $$\frac 12 mv^2 +\frac 12 I\omega^2 = \frac{J^2}{2m} + \frac{J^2x^2}{2I}$$

This means that the energy is dependent on $x$. Shouldn’t the amount of energy I give to it, depend entirely on the source, i.e. my thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that looks good (one minor point—your analysis assumes that the impulse from the thumb is perpendicular to the surface of the coin).

It makes sense that more energy is imparted when $x$ is bigger, for the same impulse. Because the coin “gets out of the way” more easily when the impulse is off center, the force from the thumb is applied through a larger displacement: more work.